# OpenCL Client Side Requirements

Tags: driver, opencl

I have implemented a project on my computer using AMD SDK v2.5 and ATI Catalyst drivers, as I have an ATI HD5570 graphics card.

I would like my executable to run on a different platform.
I would like to be able to check whether an available OpenCL platform can be found on the configuration my executable is run.
And of course the configuration can have Nvidia graphics card.

I have searched over internet but I couldn't find a final answer to my question. I am totally lost through my seach. Is there a well-known way to deploy install-client-drivers? Is there a robust-plausible and well-organized method to cover all these needs? Isn't OpenCL too messy?

Thanks and regards,

edit :
In short,

I want to provide the client computer with 1) my executable 2) any necessary files and DLL's, and i want to keep these support files minimal. So is there a way for a client computer to run my code without installing SDK's? (the client computer might have a GPU device from a different vendor)

edit 2 :

Does the requirements/installations on the client side, depend on the SDK used by the developer side? If not, why does my client receive a getplatformID error, even if he installed the latest drivers for his nvidia gpu?

edit 3 :

What should my client do, if he wanted to run an OpenCL .exe developed in a different computer (and probably using different vendors) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of OpenCL  installed  on a system you will see multiple
platforms.

Call clGetPlatformIDs  to get  the number of platforms. The count  will be greater than 1.

Call clGetPlatformIDs  again to get the list of ids.

call clGetPlatformInfo to get information on each platform.

Next decide which platform to use and then get the device information and properties.
Then establish the OpenCL  context and queues  and run kernels on the chosen platform and device combo.

How and why  does this work?  See the Khronos site for the ICD extension details

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/khr/cl_khr_icd.txt

Comment: On my computer, I can make sure that I have all the dll's, etc. ready. I already do all of the above, and can make the code work on my computer. What I cannot do is to make it run on a different computer. The getplatformID returns an error on a different configuration. I am asking how I can assure the client/other computer to run my code with his/her own opencl-compatible platform.  I am asking which files/dll's should I provide to a client who has a gpu unit with a different vendor.

Comment: I want to provide the client computer with 1) my executable 2) any necessary files and DLL's, and i want to keep these support files minimal. So is there a way for a client computer to run my code without installing SDK's?

Answer (score 0):

Well IMHO you need to know the hardware details of client computer you are planning to run, there is no universal OpenCL.dll or atiocl.dll/atiocl64.dll nvcuda.dll, that you can package along with the application and hope that everything works.

Even if you are running only CPU and not GPU you need vendor provided OpenCL.dll (openCL runtime) to be present in the client computer before you attempt to make clGetPlatformIDs... or such simmilar calls.

HTH

Comment: Ok, but for example, is there a more or less universal way to tell the client what to install? Like "if you are using nvidia gpu, please install x drivers and y packages, if you are using amd gpu please install z drivers and t packages". And does the client have to install any SDK's? Are the necessary drivers/packages that the client have to install dependant on the SDK I used? Like If I developed the code with AMD SDK, the client who has an Nvidia driver must install x, but if I had used NVidia's SDK the client should install y...?

Comment: @user1286187: I think MulticoreWare Inc tools have solution to problem you are trying to address take look at their website: http://www.multicorewareinc.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=26&Itemid=64